# Laravel save not is not working working, database not getting updated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

On my homepage, I have created a comment form that I am submitting to a table named comments. However, the database is not getting updated once I submit the form.
this is my store function

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'ask' => 'required'
    ]);
     $comments = new Comment;
     $comments->name = $request->input('name');
     $comments->email = $request->input('email');
     $comments->phone_number = $request->input('phone_number');
     $comments->ask = $request->input('ask');
     $comments->save();
     return redirect('/welcome');
}
```

this is my comment model

```
    Class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
        'name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'ask'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

this is my migration

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->integer('phone_number');
        $table->string('ask');
    });
```

Comment: what is `$commets->id`?

Comment: I was trying to save the id

Comment: since this isnt being saved, what is happening? any error? is the redirect to 'welcome' happening?

Comment: I think you have error in validation. For test this please return something after validate method in your store function and check returns true? ex: return('hi')

Comment: it is not showing error it is redirecting to welcome . siince it was updating my database then I thought I should save the id but it did not work again.

Comment: just provide the exact code you are using

Comment: this is actually the code that I am using. You are right I am having validation problem I tried to return Hi it did not.

Comment: OPS...you have error in column type...because phone_number type you set is integer..I edit my answer..please see that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now it is work I added this code in my form.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your store function:

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'ask' => 'required'
    ]);

    Comment::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
        'ask' => $request->ask,
    ]);
    return redirect('/welcome');
}
```

[Edited]

Migration:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('ask');
    });
```

but I think you have error in validation. Try to fix that too.

Comment: still the same it is not updating my Database table

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo so your problem is in validation method. before validation method use: ```return $request->all();``` and check what's posted from your form

Comment: I did I am seeing the data that entered.

Comment: In your view try to show errors with ```$errors->any()```. for see full code please visit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo see my edited answer...I think your phone_number column type is wrong